# many-to-many relationship, making the query less complicated

Tags: mysql, many-to-many

This is just an example of the tables design used in my tags system.

```
ARTICLES
id
content

TAGS
id
tag

TAGSTOARTICLES
articleid
tagid
```

**@edit** Finally after some [rubberducking](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2481480/1078027) I managed to write following queries:

---

**Just selecting articles:**

```
SELECT a.id, a.content, GROUP_CONCAT(t.tag) AS tags
FROM articles a
LEFT JOIN tagstoarticles tta ON tta.articleid = a.id
LEFT JOIN tags t ON t.id = tta.tagid
GROUP BY a.id
```

Result:

```
id  content         GROUP_CONCAT(t.tag)
1   Lorem ipsum 1   tag1,tag2
2   Lorem ipsum 2   tag1
3   Lorem ipsum 3   tag2
```

---

**Searching for tags:**

```
SELECT a.id, a.content, GROUP_CONCAT(t.tag) AS tags
FROM articles a
LEFT JOIN tagstoarticles tta ON tta.articleid = a.id
LEFT JOIN tags t ON t.id = tta.tagid
WHERE a.id IN (SELECT A.id FROM tagstoarticles M, articles A, tags T
               WHERE M.tagid = T.id
               AND (T.tag IN ('tag1'))
               AND A.id = M.articleid
               GROUP BY A.id
               HAVING COUNT( A.id )=1
)
GROUP BY a.id
```

Result:

```
id  content         GROUP_CONCAT(t.tag)
1   Lorem ipsum 1   tag1,tag2
2   Lorem ipsum 2   tag1
```

---

**But the query used for searching for tags is a mess, any idea to solve this easier?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"But how to modify this query to select all tags assigned to this article at the same time?"

```
SELECT tag FROM tags INNER JOIN tagstoarticles ON tags.id = tagstoarticles.tagid WHERE articleid=[your article's id]
```

"And how to do this when I just want to get the results without searching by tags?"

```
SELECT articles.id, tags.tag FROM articles INNER JOIN tagstoarticles ON tagstoarticles.articleid = articles.id INNER JOIN tags ON tagstoarticles.tagid = tags.id ORDER BY articles.id, articles.date
```

This gives you a distinct result row for each tag, so you'll have to apply a bit of postprocessing to convert this into a list of articles with tags. However by sorting by article id, you can be sure that all the tags for one article are returned together.

Comment: I want to simply show the articles ordered by date. But I want to show the list of all tags for this article. @edit I don't know if I understand this right but your query must be executed separately, is there any option to do this at the same time?